# Помощь в задумке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, нашел сайт https://choice.studio
Проскрольте вниз, иконка меню меняет цвет в зависимости от bg, как можно это реализовать?
может этот скрипт поможет http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/  ?
Помогут даже советы, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое CSS правило - `mix-blend-mode`. Почитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode.
Ну и пример заодно

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

.module-mixed-color {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #000000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%);
}

.module-mixed-color>.text {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-mixed-color">
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```